# Share "text" Facebook for mobile application in javascript/html

Tags: javascript, facebook, html, intel-xdk

I'm working actually on a mobile application with the Intel XDK.

I want to share some texts via facebook, but all the time, facebook need a URL, but it's a native application so i don't have any url to share ...

How can i do it ? Any idea =/ ?

(javascript/html)

thank you !

Comment: If you have no link, then there _is_ nothing to “share”. With just a text, you want to do a simple post/status update instead.

Comment: Hum ok, but on the developers facebook, when they give you code, you need a URL. Or there is another way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to do the same thing. It seems you will have to use the Facebook api that comes built into phone gap -http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/04/18/pg-facebook-plugin/